# Bash, sort after using tail

Tags: bash

I perform a tail on 3 files and then create a new file, when I go to sort this new file it says it cannot be accessed. So in the code $a,$b and $c are text files. So how can i get this to sort the new file?

```
tail -q -n -5 $a $b $c > file.txt
sort file.txt -o file.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
tail -q -n -5 $a $b $c | sort > file.txt
```

Comment: @user616731: The reason the original doesn't work is that `sort` cannot read from and write to `file.txt` at the same time.  This answer is the preferred way to do it, though you could also use a different temporary file, e.g. `sort file.txt -o result.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

What version of `sort`? For GNU coreutils 7.4 it works for me.

If you were doing

```
sort file.txt > file.txt
```

it wouldn't work because the redirection would truncate the file before `sort` read from it. However, when I do an `strace`, it reveals that `sort -o` doesn't write to the output file until the end.